# Fielding's "large-grain data objects"

Tags: rest

Roy Fielding's REST dissertation (http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm) frequently mentions 'large-grained objects' and 'large-grained data'.  For example,

*"The REST interface is designed to be efficient for large-grain
hypermedia data transfer, optimizing for the common case of the Web, but resulting
in an interface that is not optimal for other forms of architectural interaction."*

I understand that most web-pages are 'large-grained' as they are thousands of bytes long and that using UDP for streaming audio would involve small-grained data.

But in practice, what are the smallest quantities of data that a RESTful system should be used for?  A lot of examples discuss RESTful interfaces for database queries where the data being returned (minus packet info) could be only a few bytes eg a user's status.

Comment: I was wondering what 'high-grain' means as well. My assumption is it is used in the context to mean most webpages, i.e. not just some minimal control data.

Comment: 'Component interactions occur in the form of dynamically sized messages. Small or medium-grain messages are used for control semantics, but the bulk of application work is accomplished via large-grain messages containing a complete resource representation. '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really not an easy question to give an absolute answer to.

However, I would say that if your messages are so small that the interaction becomes too chatty to be viable over a regular 100 mb/s network connection, then the messages are also too small for REST.

Comment: Yes, I appreciate it's very subjective.  Thanks for your answer.